# Jest cannot test commander help function

Tags: jestjs, node-commander

With `jest` I'm not able to test `commander` module functions that result in process exit.

For example, if I pass the `--help` option or an invalid parameter like `-x` (see below) `process.exit` or `process.stdout.write` are not called as they should looking at the `commander` sources.

```
import {Command} from "commander";

let mockExit: jest.SpyInstance;
let mockStdout: jest.SpyInstance;

beforeAll(() => {
    mockExit = jest.spyOn(process, "exit").mockImplementation();
    mockStdout = jest.spyOn(process.stdout, "write").mockImplementation();
});
afterAll(() => {
    mockExit.mockRestore();
    mockStdout.mockRestore();
});
test("Ask for help", () => {

    // Setup
    const save = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.argv));
    process.argv = ["--help"]; // Same setting it to "-x"

    const program = new Command();
    program
        .option("-v, --verbose [level]", "verbose level")
        .parse(process.argv);

    expect(mockExit).toBeCalled();
    // expect(mockStdout).toBeCalled();

    // Cleanup
    process.argv = save;
});
```

What is strange is that, from the behavior of other tests, `process.argv` is not restored after this one.
Tests are in typescript and passed through `ts-jest`.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `.exitOverride()`, which is the approach Commander uses in its own tests. This means early "termination" is via a throw rather than exit.

- https://github.com/tj/commander.js#override-exit-handling

The first problem though (from comments) is the arguments. Commander expects the parse arguments follow the conventions of node with argv[0] is the application and argv[1] is the script being run, with user parameters after that.

So instead of:

```js
argsToParse = ["--help"];
```

something like:

```js
argsToParse = ['node", "dummy.js", "--help"];
```

(No need to modify `process.argv` as such.)

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. But, shame on me, the problem was caused by the wrong position of the `--help` argument in argv. This in turn was caused by the addition of a `--config <file>` to jest. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: Updated answer to cover the args issue.